# import matplotlib.pyplot failing: _tkagg.pyd not found but IS in the directory of calling module

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyd

Python 3.4 
Windows 8.1

Installed modules:
`matplotlib 1.3.1` for `py 3.4`
`numpy-MLK 1.9.0b1` for `py 3.4`
`dateutil 2.2` for `py 3.4`
`six 1.7.3` for `py 3.4`
`tcl`
`tkinter`
Also `msvcp71.dll` is in `C:\Windows\System32` (installation docs said it needed to be)

#### Upon running:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

#### I get the following error message:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#284>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "D:\Downloaded Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 98, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "D:\Downloaded Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 28, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "D:\Downloaded Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 11, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
  File "D:\Downloaded Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\tkagg.py", line 2, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import _tkagg
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

**Point being:** `Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\tkagg.py` is trying to
execute

`from matplotlib.backends import _tkagg`

but failing to do so. However `_tkagg.pyd` file **does exist** in the directory
`Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends`

Why is this not working then?

Comment: your installation or path is borked.  Try removing and reinstalling. Also make sure that if you did not compile the c-extensions your self they are build for 3.4

Comment: I tried reinstalling - didn't really change things. Apparently the problem is that the `_tkagg.pyd` file refers to `tk86t.dll` and `tcl86t.dll` neither of which it can find. Any ideas as to what I should do

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I just ran into the same problem and I found a solution, so I decided to answer it.

By taking a look at [matplotlib install documentation](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.1/users/installing.html), it says:

```
For Python 3.5 the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 needs to be installed.
```

I installed it's 64 bit version from it's [Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) (as I use 64 bit Python 3.6.3, and now the import works fine.

I hope it helps anyone that may face the same issue in the future.